# Columna file_stream de FileTables

Tags: sql-server

Una FileTable es una tabla ya predefinida en SQL Server que trabaja con la tecnología FILESTREAM para almacenar datos no estructurados en el sistema de archivos, dentro del esquema de las FileTables se encuentra la columna file_stream que es de tipo varbinary(max), ¿Qué es lo que se almacena en esta columna? ¿Es el contenido del archivo?

Answer (score 0):

Si, en la columna varBinary(max) se almacena el contenido del archivo.

Cuando creas la FileTable tienes que definir una columna como guid y una columna con la propiedad FileStream.

[FileTables](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Una columna file_stream para los datos de secuencia y un identificador
>   stream_id (GUID). (El valor de la columna file_stream es NULL para un
>   directorio).

Comment: Si es el contenido entonces, ¿el archivo se encuentra duplicado tanto en el sistema de archivos como en la tabla? y si esta duplicado ¿qué características tiene en la tabla que no tenga en el sistema de archivos, se encuentra comprimido?

Comment: Hay un termino que lo define. Stream. Del mismo modo que cuando vemos una película, no tenemos todo el contenido del archivo, sino tenemos x segundos en memoria, y según se va visualizando, a través del stream, nos va llegando el resto de la película, con la sensación de que la tenemos completa, porque la hemos visto.Si el archivo esta duplicado, tendremos dos columnas FileStream diferentes. Y no esta comprimido, salvo que el sistema de archivos lo esté.